# Automatic find and replace in Google Spreadsheet column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to automatically remove every "`-`" character from every cell in a given column.

It's my first time using scripts inside spreadsheets, so I'm kinda lost. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I advice you to do as less Google Apps Script calls as possible. Here you can just add a column in your spreadsheet and use the built in `SUBSTITUTE("search for it","search for","Google")` method (documentation [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215)).

Answer (score 9):

Just click on the column letter so that it highlights your entire column...
go to `Edit` in your menu and choose `find and replace`
in the top input bar enter `-` and leave the second one blank - then click `replace all`.

Thats it.

Answer (score 3):

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentSheet().getRange("A1:A999");
var v = range.getValues();
for ( var r = 0; r < v.length; ++r) {
  v[r][0] = v[r][0].replace(/-/g, "");
}
range.setValues(v);
```